# How to perform "Select Count" with complicated "Where" statement to compute co-occurrences?

Tags: sql, select, count

Let's have an example to declare my concern:
Suppose we have a Table (Tags) which has two columns like this

```
UserID -------------------------------- Tag
1 -------------------------------------- SQL
1 -------------------------------------- Select
1 -------------------------------------- DB
2 -------------------------------------- SQL
2 -------------------------------------- Programming
2 -------------------------------------- Code
2 -------------------------------------- Software
3 -------------------------------------- Code
4 -------------------------------------- SQL
4 -------------------------------------- Code
```

I need to count DISTINCT co-occurrences for each tag based on UserID

So, the output should be like this (with Order by Co-occurrences desc):

```
Tag -------------------------------- Co-occurrences
---------------------------------------------
SQL --------------------------------------- 5
Programming ------------------------------- 3
Code -------------------------------------- 3
Software ---------------------------------- 3
Select ------------------------------------ 2
DB ---------------------------------------- 2
```

This is just an example..

How can I make a Select statement that can do this?

I came up with one way but for only ONE specific tag:

```
SELECT count (distinct (Tag)) - 1 as Co_occurrences
FROM Tags
WHERE Tag is NOT NULL and UserID in
    (   SELECT UserID
        FROM Tags 
        where tag = 'SQL')
```

Is it possible to change the above statement to make it general for all tags in the table?

Comment: why there `Software` co-occurences 3, because in sample data I see 1. SQL 3...

Comment: we are here talking about co-occurrences based on UserID (how many tags typed with a tag by the same user) and not occurrences for the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.tag, count (distinct (t1.Tag)) - 1 as Co_occurrences
FROM Tags t1 inner join 
    Tags t2 on t1.UserId = t2.UserId 
GROUP BY t2.tag    
ORDER BY count (distinct (t1.Tag)) desc
```

Comment: You are welcome. You gave sufficient information to help formulate an answer quickly.

Answer (score 1):

A `GROUP BY` is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT 
    UserID,
    Tag,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Tag) - 1 AS Co_occurrences
FROM Tags
GROUP BY UserID, Tag
ORDER BY UserID, Tag
```

*Edit*: As mentioned in the comments, the above does not answer the question. I improved the answer of @OSA-E a bit, to explain what the `-1` is doing after the count.

```
SELECT
  [t1].[Tag],
  COUNT(DISTINCT [t2].[Tag]) AS [Co_occurrences]
FROM [Tags] [t1]
INNER JOIN [Tags] [t2] ON [t1].[UserID] = [t2].[UserID]
WHERE [t1].[Tag] <> [t2].[Tag]
GROUP BY [t1].[Tag]
ORDER BY [Co_occurrences] DESC
```

[Here is the Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6e22/7).

Comment: You are right, I did not understand the question at first. I updated my answer with a slight variation of yours. +1 for you too.

Comment: thanks for the slight variation. I did not understand the -1 initially. The where clause resolved it.